Selecting in Picker does not change selection
I am trying to display the picker and the selected emoji on the screen.
Here is the ContentView:
struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @State private var selectedEmoji = Emoji(id: 1, name: "heart", uniqueString: "\u{1F496}")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selectedEmoji.uniqueString)
                .font(.system(size: 150))
            
            Picker("Emoji Picker", selection: $selectedEmoji) {
                ForEach(viewModel.emojis) { emoji in
                    Text(emoji.uniqueString)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
            
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.getAllEmojis()
        }
    }
}

Model:
struct Emoji: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name, uniqueString: String
}

ViewModel:
class ContentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var emojis: [Emoji] = []
    
    func getAllEmojis() {
        let emoji1 = Emoji(id: 1, name: "heart", uniqueString: "\u{1F496}")
        let emoji2 = Emoji(id: 2, name: "black heart", uniqueString: "\u{2665}")
        let emoji3 = Emoji(id: 3, name: "dollarSign", uniqueString: "\u{24}")
        let emoji4 = Emoji(id: 4, name: "boom", uniqueString: "\u{2663}")
        emojis = [emoji1, emoji2, emoji3, emoji4]
    }
}

When selecting a different emoji from the picker, the value in selectedEmoji doesn't change. The UI in the first Text always shows \u{1F496}.
How can I fix it?

try adding a .tag, such as:
Picker("Emoji Picker", selection: $selectedEmoji) {
    ForEach(viewModel.emojis) { emoji in
        Text(emoji.uniqueString)
           .tag(emoji)  // <--- here
    }
}.pickerStyle(.segmented)


if my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

According to the documentation for Picker you don't need a .tag when the type iterated over in the ForEach conforms to Identifiable which is the case here.

I mean your solution works, that's not the problem but why doesn't it work for OP with their code?

@Joakim Danielson, yes, the docs says the .tag is not needed for Identifiable, and
their example code demonstrates that.
But if you change the enum Flavor: ... they use
to struct Flavor: Identifiable, Hashable, then it does not work and
you need to use a .tag(flavor). I guess they forgot to tell us that
it does not work with structs.
However if you make the selection variable, the id type (eg Int),
then there is no need for the .tag.

Thanks. So it was that simple, enum instead of struct.
